# Using nginx location with differently named HTML files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want my www.example.com/select to return the file /srv/www/example/static/html/select.html
I've got my example.conf set up like the following, but it doesn't do the trick

```
server {
  server_name  mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

  root /srv/www/mywebsite/static;

  #charset koi8-r;
  #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

  location = / {
      index  html/index.html;
  }

  location = /select {
      index html/select.html;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Although index.html is returned, attempting to get /select will log this error

```
2018/04/28 08:16:59 [error] 17160#17160: *43106 open() "/srv/www/mywebsite/static/select" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How should I configure my nginx to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` directive operates on URIs that end with a `/`, so will not work in this case. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

If you only have the one URI, you can use:

```
location = /select {
    rewrite ^ /html/select.html last;
}
```

Is there a reason you have left the `/html/` suffix off the `root` value? A more general solution might be:

```
root /srv/www/mywebsite/static/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: The try_files solution is perfect! Thanks a lot, and a good day to you!